# git: question about creating branches and cloning repos

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit

I have just created a branch from `master` called `new_branch`

So I have checkout that new branch, add a new file, and then add/commit/push.

```
git add new_file.php
git commit -m "A new file"
git push origin new_branch
```

So after that, I have cloned my repo example, and the thing is that that file I have added in the new branch is not in the master branch of cloned work-tree. What should I do to find it that new file in the master branch of the cloned work-tree?

NOTE: sorry because of the imprecision of the title. Maybe someone wants to change it.

Comment: It sounds like you are confusing `master` (an actual branch) with `HEAD` (a *pointer* to a branch, indicating which branch will be affected by `git commit` et al.). You committed the new file to `new_branch`, not `master`, and that's the branch you pushed to. So when you clone the remote repository again, you need to check out `new_branch` again to see `new_file`.

Comment: The `new_branch` argument refers to the branch on `origin` that should be updated, not the branch in your local repository to push *from*. That is always whatever branch is currently checked out (which happens to be the *local* branch also named `new_branch`).

Comment: @chepner yes, you are right: I have just checkout the branch `new_branch` on my cloned repo, and I can find the file. But, how can I get that file in `master` branch automatically after cloning?

Comment: There are several ways, but which one you choose depends on what kind of relationship you want between `master` and `new_branch`. You can merge `new_branch` into `master`; you can cherry-pick a single commit from `new_branch` to `master`; you can check out `new_branch` (adding `new_file` to your working directory`, then check out `master` (leaving `new_file` as an untracked file in your working directory), then commit `new_file` to `master` as if it were a brand new file.

Comment: Which option you choose might also depend on the answer to the question "Why did you commit `new_file` to `new_branch` instead of `master` in the first place?"

Comment: @chepner wel, I have read that to made changes I should create a new branch, made the changes and then add/commit/push them.

Comment: Read where? Typically, you do so with the intention of merging the branch back into the branch you originally branched off of. There are various work flows one might follow when using Git; branches are just part of implementing each work flow, and you can't say that any particular use of a branch is right or wrong on its own.

Comment: @chepner so for having my new file in `master` branch, I will have to do as last step `git push origin master`, rigth? there is nothing bad on doing that, right?

Comment: Probably not, given this simple example, but you typically don't push one branch to another different branch. Either `git checkout master; git merge new_branch; git push origin`, or just add `new_file` to `master` in the first place without creating a new branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question indicates that you did not fully understand what a branch is and what the master branch is. I would recommend reading more and doing tutorials.

To answer the question with a very basic workflow, that you could use: I assume that "new_branch" is a feature branch and your workflow is to merge features branches into a single master branch (a classic, simple git workflow).
switch to master branch:

```
git checkouter master
```

merge your feature:

```
git merge new_branch
```

(fix merge conflicts, since you just add a file, there should not be any)
publish the changes:

```
git push origin
```

Now you have merged your new feature into the master branch and every clone will contain your feature. As mentioned by @chepner git offers much more possibilities, however, for learning and understanding branches this is a simple starting point.